# nodeJS - how i connect with MySQL and display the result in localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js

I wrote this code

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var mysql = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  user: 'root',
  password: '',
  database: 'nodejs'
});

connection.connect(function (err) {
  if (!err) {
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM nodetest', function (err, rows) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
      }
      var json = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rows))[0];
      console.log(json);
    });
    console.log("Database is connected");
  } else {
    console.log("Error connecting database");
  }
});



http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {
    "Content-Type": "test/html"
  });
  response.end('here my data');
}).listen(7777);
```

and I have a problem with display the result in my localhost as i json

what is the bast way to read table and convert it to json and display in localhost

Answer (score 1):

what does [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) do?

> The JSON.stringify() method converts a JavaScript value to a JSON
>   string, optionally replacing values if a replacer function is
>   specified, or optionally including only the specified properties if a
>   replacer array is specified.

What does [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) do?

> The JSON.parse() method parses a JSON string, constructing the
>   JavaScript value or object described by the string.

So basically, one operation is the inverse of the other. And therein lies your problem:

```
var json = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rows))[0];
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is the problem - I suspect it has more to do with both the `createServer` and mysql `connect` being async, and getting one to call the other.

Comment: if I understood the question correctly, the OP is just unable to return JSON

Comment: Yeah, its not at all clear what the problem is. But I was assuming that because of `response.end('here my data');` and in there there is no reference to `json`.

Comment: But yes, looking closely it does seem that he is not returning anything to the browser. Nevertheless the JSON generation itself is broken

Answer (score 1):

Since you are requiring express, I'm assuming you want to use it.
You can create an index route with `app.get('/', function(req,res){})`. A fast way to display your data as json from your mysql database would be:

```
var express = require('express');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var app = express();

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'nodejs'
});

// localhost:7777/
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    connection.connect(function(err) {
        if (!err) {
            connection.query('SELECT * FROM nodetest', function(err, rows) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    return;
                }
                var json = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rows))[0];
                res.send(json); // Send the JSON back as a application/json type response.
            });
            console.log("Database is connected");
        } else {
            console.log("Error connecting database");
        }
    });
})

app.listen(7777, function() {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 7777!')
});
```